# How can I get a sequence of dates in bash?

Tags: bash

In Z shell there is a command called dseq which produces consecutive dates.  For example:

```
$ dseq 5
2022-05-08
2022-05-09
2022-05-10
2022-05-11
2022-05-12
```

Is there a similar command in bash?  I tried the following which gets me close to the desired output.

```
$ seq -f "2022-05-%g" 5
2022-05-1
2022-05-2
2022-05-3
2022-05-4
2022-05-5
```

Two issues:

1. how can I pad the days with `0` so the output contains two-digit days?
2. how can I start the sequence from today versus the first of the month?

Desired output should match output of `$ dseq 5` above.

Comment: `dseq` is a program, not a built-in command of zsh. If you are on Ubuntu, try to install dateutils: `sudo apt-get install -y dateutils`. Then `dateseq 5` works. It was apparently recently renamed: ubuntu 16 was called dseq: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dateutils.dseq.1.html now dateseq: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dateutils.dseq.1.html

Comment: @masterxilo I am not Ubuntu. I am on MacOS

Comment: @jgg then `brew install dateutils` should do it.

Comment: @Maroun this helped.  And then I typed `dateseq 2022-05-01`

Answer (score 4):

You can have something like:

```sh
$ for i in {1..5}; do date -d "20220507+$i day" +%Y-%m-%d; done
2022-05-08
2022-05-09
2022-05-10
2022-05-11
2022-05-12
```

Comment: I get the following error: `date: illegal option -- d
usage: date [-jnRu] [-r seconds|file] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]]
            [-I[date | hours | minutes | seconds]]
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`

Comment: @jgg Try `brew install coreutils` and then use `gdate`. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810599/date-d-not-working-on-mac).

Comment: The `-d` option is specific to GNU `date`. If you are on MacOS, the system `date` command is somewhat clunkier, so perhaps a more elegant solution would be e.g. a simple Perl script.

Comment: on BSD it would be `date -v "+${i}d" +%Y-%m-%d`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MacOS and don't want to install GNU `date` (which is what provides the nonstandard `-d` option which you'll find in most answers to related questions) you will need to perform relative date calculations yourself. Perhaps like this:

```
base=$(date +"%s")
for((i=0; i<5; ++i)); do
    date -r $((i * 24 * 60 * 60 + base)) +%Y-%m-%d
done
```

This avoids any complex `date` manipulations; if you need them, they are somewhat unobvious, and less versatile than the GNU `date` extensions - see, for example, [How to convert date string to epoch timestamp with the OS X BSD `date` command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348963/how-to-convert-date-string-to-epoch-timestamp-with-the-os-x-bsd-date-command)

For what it's worth, GNU `date` (and generally GNU userspace utilities) are the default on most Linux platforms.

With GNU `date` you could do `date -d @timestamp +format` where MacOS/BSD uses `date -r timestamp +format`.

If you need a portable solution, POSIX is not much help here, but a reasonably *de facto* portable solution is to use e.g. Perl. For inspiration, perhaps review [What is a good way to determine dates in a date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635993/what-is-a-good-way-to-determine-dates-in-a-date-range)

```
perl -le 'use POSIX qw(strftime);
    $t = time;
    for $_ (1..5) {
        print strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime($t));
        $t += 24 * 60 * 60 }'
```

Demo (on Linux): https://ideone.com/WkAoib

In case it's not obvious, both these solutions get the current time's epoch (seconds since Jan 1, 1970) and then add increments of 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds to jump ahead one day at a time.